# jenkins pipeline catch build_job info for a failed parallel build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Does anyone know how to catch the failed job's number in a parallel pipeline execution while still have failFast feature working for short-circuiting of builds in the event of a job failure? I know i can kind-of make it work if i do "propagate = false" while running the build step but that kills the failFast feature, and i need that.

For example, below is my code and i want the value of variable achild_job_info inside the catch block as well.

```
build_jobs = [“Build_A”, “ Build_B”, “ Build_C”]

def build_job_to_number_mappings = [:]
// in this hashmap we'll place the jobs that we wish to run
def branches = [:] 
def achild_job_info = ""
def abuild_number = ""
for (x in build_jobs) {
    def abuild = x 
    branches[abuild] = { 
        stage(abuild){
            retry(2) {
                try {
                    achild_job_info = build job: abuild
                    echo “ achild_job_info”  // —>  this gives: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@232601dc
                    abuild_number = achild_job_info.getId()
                    build_job_to_number_mappings[abuild] = achild_job_info.getNumber()
                } catch (err) {
                    echo “ achild_job_info: ${achild_job_info } “  // —> This comes empty. I want the runwrapper here as well, just like in the try block. 
                    abuild_job_number = abuild_job_info.getId()
                    build_job_to_number_mappings[abuild] = achild_job_info.getNumber()
                } // try-catch
        } // stage
   } // branches
} // for
branches.failFast = true
parallel branches
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way i could find out for now is to use the value of the 'exception string' and split it to get the current build number and name. I am not sure that is the most robust way to do this but works for now. Posting this reply to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid throwing by turning off the exception propagation:

```
achild_job_info = build job: abuild, propagate: false
if(achild_job_info.result == "SUCCESS") { ...
```

P.S.  A little late, but I just got here looking for this myself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).